# display data of form in html

Tags: php, html

I have a form in HTML. After submitting it, I want to show the name of file in the same HTML page. I use a PHP file called `upLoad.php` to echo the name of the file but what should I do to show the name of file in the same html page? 
I also don't want to use php code in my html code.
**HTML:**

```
<form action="upLoad.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep `action` empty

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And put this at the start of the page

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
  else
  {
    $print  = "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    $print .= "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    $print .= "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    $print .= "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
}
```

You can now use the `$print` variable anywhere in the same page to show the result by using `echo $print`

Comment: but I don't want to use php code in my html code . I want to have them separatly

Comment: I don't get what you mean by `I don't want to use php code in my html code. I want to have them separatly`

Comment: I want to use the data of form in special part of my web face for example to change text of a text area , I don't want to use echo I want to have this php file in my server side so  I can't use its information  directly

Comment: Oh..in that case you'll have to use Ajax. Here is a tutorial to get you started http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot receive data with HTML only so you'll have to make your first page a .php with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES))
{
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
     echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
     echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
}
?>
<form action="thispage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And if you end up working with multiple forms you can use a get variable on your action like this:

```
<?php 
if($_GET['delete'] == 1)
{
 //PHP code
}
elseif($_GET['update'] == 1)
{
 //PHP code
}
?>

<form action='thispage.html?delete=1' method='POST' >
 <!-- html inputs -->
</form>

<form action='thispage.html?update=1' method='POST' >
 <!-- html inputs -->
</form>
```

Or just use an hidden input if you prefer not to have any GET variables like so:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['delete'] == 1)
{
 //PHP code
}
elseif($_POST['update'] == 1)
{
 //PHP code
}
?>

<form action='thispage.html' method='POST' >
 <input type='hidden' name='delete' value='1' />
 <!-- html inputs -->
</form>

<form action='thispage.html' method='POST' >
 <input type='hidden' name='update' value='1' />
 <!-- html inputs -->
</form>
```

Comment: And you can also use <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> instead of thispage.php

Comment: See @asprin's answer, you can just have `action=""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use php on the HTML file, you could use jquery form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/